# when i refresh a page on http-server in angular . Page says not found

Tags: angular

when i refresh a page on http-server in angular . Page says not found Could you please help me

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up the web server properly. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45801290/390161) has a detailed explanation.

Comment: I got a answer in link that you have mentioned